# conflicting types for allocArray

Tags: c

guys I'm trying to compile my program in c but I'm getting this error (conflicting types for allocArray)?

Here is my code:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> int number(int);
> char *allocArray(int);
>
> int main ()
> {
>         printf("Enter a number: ");
>         int userNumber;
>         scanf("%d", &userNumber);
>         int m= number(userNumber);
>         printf("\nThe number is %d", m);
>         printf("\n");
>
> printf("*****************************************************\n");
>         printf("The array is %s", alloArray(5));
>
> }
>
> int number(int n)
> {
>
> int num = n;
>
> return num;
> }
>
> char *alloArray(int num)
> {
>         char *addr;
>         addr = (char *) malloc(num);
>         //addr = char[num];
>         return addr;
> }
> ```

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to accomplish? You have a _large_ amount of redundant code, and you're not using `malloc()` correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array and return a pointer to it for the second method.

Comment: @Khalid - You do that, but that action by itself is useless. You allocate the array, but it doesn't contain anything, so you then print it out, even though it probably contains nothing (or worse, garbage). The only pointer to that array is then lost, so you can't `free()` your array later. Your `allocArray()` function serves no real purpose - it just calls `malloc()` and you could (and, IMHO should) just call `malloc()` in its place. Unless you're using C++ (or a C++ compiler) you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`, and `malloc()` takes `size_t` parameter, not an `int` which...

Comment: ...is a signed integer (and you' rarely want to allocate an array of -5 characters, do you?). Your `main()` function should make a `char *p = malloc(5);` then use `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` or something similar to write data into `p` before you print it.

Comment: Oh I kinda understand that now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome. I remember being horribly confused by pointers when I was first learning C. They're going to be very confusing for a while and then will suddenly make sense. I hope we can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelt `allocArray` as `alloArray` (twice, in fact).

Comment: I know it there is a stupid mistake!! I hate when I have this kind of mistakes.